# On the sigma-field induced by a continuous function

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

Let $f:X\to Y$ by a continuous function, where $X,Y$ are metric spaces. Let $\mathcal B(X)$ be the Borel sigma-field on $X$. Consider the sigma-field $\{B\in \mathcal B(X):B=f^{-1}(f(B))\}$ on $X$ that consists of the *invariant* Borel sets. Is this sigma field equal to $\{f^{-1}(A): A\in \mathcal B(Y)\}$?

It is easy to show that the latter is included in the former.

**Update:** Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are complete and separable.

Comment: What makes your collection a sigma field? It is not clear to me that it is closed under complementation.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $B=f^{-1}(f(B))\iff\exists U [B=f^{-1}(U)]$ and RHS implies almost directly that also the complement of $B$ is the preimage of complement of $U$. In short: complements of $f$-saturated sets are $f$-saturated.

Comment: @drhab I don't think the equivalence you have stated is correct. In fact that the class defined by OP need not be a sigma filed and hence the claim made in the question is wrong. ( You cannot simply say 'for some U' unless $f$ is surjective).

Comment: Let $B=f^{-1}(U)$. Then $f(B)\subseteq U$ so that $f^{-1}(f(B))\subseteq f^{-1}(U)=B$. Conversely if $x\in B$ then $f(x)\in f (B)$ so that $x\in f^{-1}(f(B))$. The other side of the equivalence is obvious: just take $U=f(B)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I answered on your comment but forgot to address

Comment: @drhab Got it. Thanks for being so patient with me.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy It happens seldom but always feels as an honour to teach a very good teacher :-).

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathbb R$ be the underlying set of $X$ and $Y$, let $X$ be equipped with discrete topology and $Y$ with usual topology. Both are metrizable.

Let $f$ be the identity function and observe that the function is continuous.

Then the first collection is $\wp (\mathbb R) $ and the latter is $\mathcal B (\mathbb R) $ hence is  a proper subcollection of the first.

Comment: Right. But what if we assume that $X$ and $Y$ are complete and separable?

Comment: I updated the question.